# Конструкция языка Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Как называется эта конструкция языка Kotlin (пустые скобки после точки) и какой смысл она имеет?

```
CoroutineScope.()
```

Правильно ли я понимаю, что это обозначает любую функцию расширения (в данном примере для класса `CoroutineScope`), или нет?

Comment: Хорошо было бы расширить пример. Полагаю, что это часть [лямбды с получателем](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#function-literals-with-receiver), просто без параметров

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Указанная конструкция похожа на декларирование [типобезопасного строителя](https://kotlinlang.ru/docs/reference/type-safe-builders.html), чтоб показать для чего он может понадобиться нужно рассмотреть типичный случай создания двух связанных объектов в Java:

```
PostAddress address = new PostAddress();
address.setCountry("Россия");
address.setZipCode("99099");
User user = new User();
user.setName("Анонимус");
user.setPostAddress(address);
```

Как можно заметить полезной информации тут немного, весь церемониальный код можно отнести к синтаксическому шуму который мешает воспринимать человеку значимую информацию, такую как адрес и даже можно не заметить связь между User и PostAddress.

Котлин позволяет к свойствам класса обращаться без использования get/set методов, потому там та же самая запись будет чуть проще:

```
val address = PostAddress()
address.country = "Россия"
address.zipCode = "99099"
val user = User()
user.name = "Анонимус"
user.postAddress = address
```

Но при использовании типобезопасного строителя мы можем тоже самое записать так:

```
val user = User {
  name = "Анонимус"
  postAddress {
    country = "Россия"
    zipCode = "99099"
  } 
}
```

Для того чтоб можно было именно так, кратко, конструировать экземпляры класса User мы должны определить сам класс так:

```
class User {
    var name: String? = null
    var postAddress: PostAddress? = null 

    constructor(block123: User.()->Unit) {
        block123()
    }

    fun postAddress(init111: PostAddress.()->Unit) {
        val postAddress = PostAddress()
        postAddress.init111()
        this.postAddress = postAddress
    }
}
```

Имена block12345 и init111 выбраны специально, чтоб показать, что никаких ключевых слов языка не используется.